# Azure Active Directory B2C new user invite to set their initial password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In short: how to set up Azure B2C to pre-create users and invite them to set their initial password (rather than reset it).

We have public facing website that an organisation can pay for and it gives them access to their own area.  We add one or more user's email addresses to our database to grant them a login.  Privileged users at the organisation can invite other users to grant them access to their organisation's area.

We wish to move our authentication, session and password management from a home grown solution to Azure AD B2C.

A new user currently receives a friendly invitation email with a hyperlink that contains a token that gives them permission to set their password.

We could create a custom policy to handle this but I really don't want to go down that route due to their complexity and shelf life.

The only way that I've found "out of the box" is to create the user in Azure AD (not problem with that), set a temporary password and email them an invite asking them to "reset" their password.  The reset part is very unclean as they are not resetting their password, they are setting their initial password and this will be confusing.

Also note that we do not want the user to be able to change their email to something like a hotmail account, as the admin must be in charge of this to ensure they use their work email.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMarshall, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   In your scenario, I would suggest you **configure an application registration in Azure AD B2C and configure user flows in it for resetting the password for every user logging in it**. Also, while `registering an application in Azure AD B2C`, you can select the option for **‘Accounts in this organizational directory only (Default Directory only - Single tenant)’** and **integrate it with your website in the frontend API such that the user flow to reset the password after verifying the email address comes up for every user**.

For the above said configuration, kindly refer to the below documentation link for more details as it describes the configuration for registering users of a single tenant/organization: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow***

Also, refer to the below documentation link for `resetting the initial temporary password using the user flow section as setting up a user flow is a very simple process` as described below: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow***